# Reading a file in Python: slurp or filter?

Tags: performance, python-3.x

I want to compare the effect of processing a stream as a filter (that is, get a bit, process, rinse), against slurping (that is, get all information, then process).

However, when I run the two codes below, I get comparable results. I was expecting to obtain a much worse result in the slurp version.

Are the codes snippets below doing anything different as described above? If they are equivalent, how could I adapt one of them for testing the filter/slurp difference?

I was testing the scripts with:

```
jot 100000000 | time python3 dont_slurp.py > /dev/null
jot 100000000 | time python3 slurp.py > /dev/null
```

`Jot` generates numbers from 1 to x. The codes snippets just numerate the lines.

Filter:

```
import sys
lineno = 0
for line in sys.stdin:
    lineno += 1
    print("{:>6} {}".format(lineno, line[:-1]))
```

Slurp:

```
import sys

f = sys.stdin
lineno = 0

for line in f:
    lineno += 1
    print('{:>6} {}'.format(lineno, line[:-1]))
```

Comment: The "Slurp" version is not doing what you think it does.  Both versions are reading one line at a time.  To read all lines at once you'd do `for line in f.readlines()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code samples are not doing what you think.  All `f = sys.stdin` does is set `f` to the same file handle.  The lines `for line in f:` and `for line in sys.stdin:` are functionally identical.

What you want is this:

```
 import sys

 lineno = 0

 for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
      lineno += 1
      print('{:>6} {}'.format(lineno, line[:-1]))
```

`readlines()` returns a list, one element per line in the file.  I believe it is *not* a generator, so you get the full list.  The file handle itself acts as a generator, giving you one line at a time.

You should see performance differences with `readline()`.

However, the answer to "which is better?" is "it depends".  When you read line by line, you're making a system call, which in turn causes the OS to read file contents off of the disk in blocks.  These blocks are likely larger than the size of the average line, and the block is likely cached.  That means sometimes you hit the disk, taking lots of time, other times you hit the cache, taking little time.

When you read all at once, you load every byte from the file into memory at once.  If you have enough free memory to hold all file contents, then this takes exactly the same amount of time as the line-by-line version.  In both cases, it is basically just the time required to read the whole file sequentially with some little bit of overhead.

The difference is the case where you don't have enough free memory to hold the entire file.  In that case, you read the whole file, but parts of it get swapped back out to disk by the virtual memory system.  They then have to get pulled in again when you access that particular line.

Exactly how much time is lost depends on how much memory is in use, how much other activity is going on on your system, etc., so it can't be quantified in general.

This is a case where you honestly shouldn't worry about it until there is a problem.  Do what is more natural in the code and only worry about performance if your program is too slow.

Comment: I think an additional point that might be worth pointing out is that given filtering, you might be able to do I/O and CPU work in parallel.